# E-Mails are not storing. Postfix, Dovecot & MySQL

Tags: mysql, postfix, dovecot

I am trying to set up a mail server with Postfix & Dovecot using MySQL to store the aliases, domain & user.

The issue is, users are not receiving emails.

According to the log files, the received emails are saved, but the result is that they are not stored.

But something happens anyway, because a folder /mail is created, in which there is then a .imap with another folder /INBOX with the files:

- dovecot.index.cache
- dovecot.index.log

```
Log: Oct 18 19:59:22 vmd119784 postfix/qmgr[1939]: 43475800A6C: from=<test@mydomain.art>, size=351, nrcpt=1 (queue active)

Oct 18 19:59:22 vmd119784 dovecot: lmtp(2126): Connect from local

Oct 18 19:59:22 vmd119784 postfix/lmtp[2125]: 43475800A6C: to=<test1@mydomain.art>, relay=mail.mydomain.art[private/dovecot-lmtp], delay=0.01, delays=0/0/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 <test1@mydomain.art> 8BOlEPocMGVOCAAAulSNBQ Saved)

Oct 18 19:59:22 vmd119784 dovecot: lmtp(test1@mydomain.artt)<2126><8BOlEPocMGVOCAAAulSNBQ>: msgid=<20231018175922.43475800A6C@mydomain.art>: saved mail to INBOX

Oct 18 19:59:22 vmd119784 dovecot: lmtp(2126): Disconnect from local: Client has quit the connection (state=READY)

Oct 18 19:59:22 vmd119784 postfix/qmgr[1939]: 43475800A6C: removed
```

I put the mail location at "/var/mail/vhosts/mydomain.art".

Config files that I have edited:

**/etc/postfix/main.cf/**

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no

append_dot_mydomain = no
readme_directory = no

compatibility_level = 2

smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.art/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.art/privkey.pem

smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous, noplaintext
smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous

smtp_tls_CApath=/etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes

smtpd_helo_restrictions =
        permit_mynetworks,
        permit_sasl_authenticated,
        reject_invalid_helo_hostname,
        reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
        permit_mynetworks,
        permit_sasl_authenticated,
        reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
        reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
        reject_unlisted_recipient,
        reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sender_restrictions =
        permit_mynetworks,
        permit_sasl_authenticated,
        reject_non_fqdn_sender,
        reject_unknown_sender_domain
smtpd_relay_restrictions =
        permit_mynetworks,
        permit_sasl_authenticated,
        defer_unauth_destination


myhostname = mail.mydomain.art
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases

mydomain = mydomain.art
myorigin = $mydomain

mydestination = localhost
relayhost = 

mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128

mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +

inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all

virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp

virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/virtual-alias-maps.cf, mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/virtual-email2email.cf

disable_vrfy_command = yes
strict_rfc821_envelopes = yes

#smtpd_etrn_restrictions = reject
#smtpd_reject_unlisted_sender = yes
#smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient = yes

smtpd_delay_reject = yes
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtp_always_send_ehlo = yes

smtpd_timeout = 30s
smtp_helo_timeout = 15s
smtp_rcpt_timeout = 15s
smtpd_recipient_limit = 40
minimal_backoff_time = 180s
maximal_backoff_time = 3h

invalid_hostname_reject_code = 550
non_fqdn_reject_code = 550
unknown_address_reject_code = 550
unknown_client_reject_code = 550
unknown_hostname_reject_code = 550
unverified_recipient_reject_code = 550
unverified_sender_reject_code = 550
```

**/etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf**

```
!include_try /usr/share/dovecot/protocols.d/*.protocol

protocols = imap pop3 lmtp
postmaster_address = postmaster at mydomain.art

mail_location = maildir:/var/mail/vhosts/%d/%n/
mail_privileged_group = mail

!include conf.d/*.conf
!include_try local.conf
```

**/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf/**

```
mail_location = mbox:~/mail:INBOX=/var/mail/%u

namespace inbox {
    inbox = yes
}

mail_privileged_group = mail

protocol !indexer-worker { 

}
```

There are no errors or warnings in the logs that might indicate that vmail the user, has no access or a path cannot be found, so I am a bit frustrated.

I tried to exchange mails local, sending itself works too. Also, to outside to my gmail address.

Other than that, I checked my configs again, but unfortunately couldn't find anything that made me solve the problem.

Comment: try to get more specific than "not receiving". So you have Dovecot saying its store to INBOX and some other observation where you cannot see the messages? Go run `find /var/mail/vhosts/` and see where the files are, chances are you have a mismatch between what IMAP user you are logging in, and where you expect expanded aliases to deliver your mail.

Comment: When showing your configuration, please use the commands as recommended in the [tag](https://serverfault.com/tags/postfix/info) [descriptions](https://serverfault.com/tags/dovecot/info) to rule out a mismatch between what you *think* you configured in some file, and what is *effective* configuration taking into account other files & parsing errors etc.

Comment: if you never every setup this kind, I really appreciate it if you would use for your own safety somewhat like mailcow, which comes as ready to use and is well known as a professional provider product. I am not associated with it even I repeatedly mentioned it ;)